# Return a list of 'nearby' addresses from a 'single' longitude and latitude?

Tags: python, pandas, reverse-geocoding, geopy

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
from geopy.extra.rate_limiter import RateLimiter

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="return_addresses")
query = "41.03798, -73.76955"
location = geolocator.reverse(query, exactly_one=True)

print(location)
# print(location.address)
# print(location.raw)

# print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

# print(location.raw)
```

Using reverse in GeoPy, is it possible to return a **list** of 'nearby' addresses from a 'single' longitude and latitude? I have tried changing the "exactly_one=True" to "False", however I still only return one specific address. I have also added the 'zoom' parameter and that does nothing but return a higher level of return like a single county or city. I'm hoping to return a list or tuple of addresses from entering a **single** lat long query. Does anyone one know of a GeoPy setting that accounts for a range or zoom to return more addresses from a single query "lat/long". Sorry for repeating the point a few times. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Is this a case where I would need to use a service API key to open up more results? In a search on this subject I came across a mention of OverPy 'overpass' to perform a task such as this. However, I have not seen example python code making this API call of a single point (address or lat/long) to a multiple address return.

Comment: Nominatim doesn't return more than 1 object in reverse geocoding, see https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Reverse/#parameters . You may want to try a different service. IIRC the Google geocoder doesn't have such limitation.

Comment: Thank you for this information on google geocoder! Looking at it now.